# Playwright - won't launch full screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright, playwright-test

I am launching my text execution with the new playwright test runner. Unfortunately I can't get it to start in a full screen mode.

I am using the following code:

```js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
const { HomePage } = require('../lib/Homepages');
const playwright = require('@playwright/test');

test.describe('Home Test Suite', () => {
  let homePage;

  test.beforeAll(async () => {
    const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({ args: ['--start-maximized'] });
    const context = await browser.newContext({ viewport: null });
    const page = await context.newPage();
    homePage = new HomePage(page);
    await homePage.loadapp();
  });

  test.afterAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    await browser.close();
  });

  test.describe('test1', () => {
    test('test', async () => {
      expect(await homepage.x()).toBeTruthy();
      // Act
      await homePage.dosomething('Word');

      // Assert
      expect(await homePage.isItCorrect()).toBeTruthy;
    });
   });
   });
```

After running npm run test. I receive the following error:

> browser.newContext: "deviceScaleFactor" option is not supported with
> null "viewport"

Any idea how to get it to work?

Comment: I’d recommend to use a fixed viewport size. Imagine you have a coworker whom’s screen is 720x1024 and yours is 3800x2100 then the application might behave completely different. Playwright is about reproducible end-to-end tests and so we embrace a fixed viewport size. (FTR, see here for the feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4046) And regarding the error, you probably have a device set inside your playwright.config.ts which includes the deviceScaleFactor.

Comment: I understand thank you! Also yes, the error was caused by ...devices['Desktop Chrome']. Thanks again.

Comment: @MaxSchmitt web development is all about supporting different screen sizes and dynamically changing window size, thats why responsive apps have quite an emphasis on animated view port updates.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Playwright in .NET and here is my solution to this issue.

Specify maximized in BrowserTypeLaunchOptions

```
new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions()
{
  Args = new string[] { "--start-maximized" }
}
```

Initialize BrowserContext with NoViewport

```
Context = await Browser.NewContextAsync(new BrowserNewContextOptions()
{
  ViewportSize = ViewportSize.NoViewport
});
```

Comment: for some reason when I follow this code, I get a browser opened in fullscreen but immediately goes to restore mode window.

Comment: This worked for me as this. using the C# MSTest Playwright Class

await using var browser = await Playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
        { Headless = false, Args = new[] { "--start-maximized" } } );
        var context = await browser.NewContextAsync(new BrowserNewContextOptions() { ViewportSize = ViewportSize.NoViewport});
        var page = await context.NewPageAsync();

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to figure the correct config-combination due to serious lack of documentation about it.

Basically the error `browser.newContext: "deviceScaleFactor" option is not supported with null "viewport"`
occurs because `DeviceDescriptor` and `viewport=null` can't be defined at the same time in a single project.

You haven't share your playwright config file, and by default there's at least chromium-project defined.
So, unless you've changed it, it should be the root-cause of the problem.

### First Way - Via playwright.config file (project-level)

1. Add `args: ["--start-maximized"]` to the `launchOptions`
2. **Remove** the *DeviceDescriptor* from your project
3. Set `viewport: null` in your project

Example `playwright.config.ts` file:

```
// playwright.config.ts file
import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";

export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    launchOptions: {
      // 1
      args: ["--start-maximized"],
    },
  },

  projects: [
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: {
        // 2 (Make sure device is not set)
        // ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],

        // 3
        viewport: null,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

### Second Way - In the test itself

```js
const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--start-maximized"],
});
const context = await browser.newContext({ viewport: null });
const page = await context.newPage();
```

Again, note that you follow these steps:

1. Add `args: ["--start-maximized"]` to the `launchOptions`
2. **Remove** the *DeviceDescriptor* from your **project configuration**
3. Set `viewport: null` in the `BrowserContext`

Answer (score 0):

For python the following seems to works:

```py
webEngine = sync_playwright().start()
browser = webEngine.chromium.launch_persistent_context(
            user_data_dir= "path/to/persist/dir/",
            headless = False,
            args= ["--start-fullscreen"], # To disable all user controls except alt+F4 you can use "--kiosk" instead
            ignore_default_args= ["--enable-automation"], # ignore this line if you don't mind the "use of automation" message
            no_viewport = True
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

The error was caused by the playwright.config.js.

I had the following code:

```
    projects: [
        {
            name: 'chromium',
            use: {
                ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
            },
        },
]
```

Commenting out the 'use'
has fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
projects: [
    {
      name: "edge",
      use: {
        channel: 'msedge',
        launchOptions: {
          args: ["--start-maximized"], // starting the browser in full screen
          slowMo: 1000, // a 1000 milliseconds pause before each operation. Useful for slow systems.
        },
      },
    },
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: {
        ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
        launchOptions: {
          args: ["--start-fullscreen"], // starting the browser in full screen
          slowMo: 1000, // a 1000 milliseconds pause before each operation. Useful for slow systems.
        },
      },
    },
    {
      name: "firefox",
      use: { ...devices["Desktop Firefox"] },
    },
  ],
```