Unable to run tests on browserstack with playwright in fullsize
Browserstack is not launching playwright tests in full size
have connected Browserstack using chromium and provided viewport as null
`
        let browser = await chromium.connect({
            wsEndpoint:
                `wss://cdp.browserstack.com/playwright?caps=` +
                `${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(caps))}`,
        });

        let context = let context = await browser.newContext({viewport:null})
        let browserStackpage: Page = await context.newPage();
        await browserStackpage.close();
        await browser.close()

`
Have provided view port as null but cant provide lauchargs as it goes with launch method of chromium

Also, see the second method in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77550024/19574650
